# cuda stream with breath first: kernels and D2H transfers

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

In reference to page 21 in this presentation file:
http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf

I don't understand  why sequentially issued kernels delay signals and block D2H transfers. Is it the case for modern CUDA devices

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The presentation dates from 2011 and had primarily Fermi architecture (cc2.x) devices in view.

In those devices, the ability to have full concurrency of D2H and H2D copies, along with one or more kernels, in a pipelined algorithm (i.e. a sequence of D2H, H2D, and kernel launches, occurring in a regular order) would depend on the actual issue order (i.e. the sequence of operations in the host thread).  This is due to "false dependencies" that the Fermi architecture inserted between operations in separate streams, which should not have any dependency on each other.  A brief description of the reason for this is given on slides 20 and 21 in that presentation.  I don't believe a more detailed description of this architectural characteristic of Fermi has been published.

Kepler introduced Hyper-Q, which was intended to reduce or eliminate this effect.  The architecture should not introduce such false dependencies, and so it should be possible with Kepler (cc3.x) and beyond to issue operations in either a depth-first order, or a breadth-first order, and still witness concurrency amongst the data transfers and kernel operations.